# Keeping variable scope throughout a script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables

I have a script that has a number of select into statements that connects to various linked servers.

I want to be able to run the script multiple times but in each case the servers and databases will change and a couple of table names will change.

I was hoping to use variables to define the servers once at the beiginning with something like what follows, but of course they goes out of scope as they are only local variables.

```
declare @table_that_changes varchar(100) 
declare @linked_server1 varchar(20)
declare @linked_server2 varchar(20)
declare @DB_onserver1 varchar(100) 
declare @DB_onserver2 varchar(100)
select @linked_server1 = '[server109]',
       @linked_server2 = '[server104]',
       @DB_onserver1 = '[database203434]',
       @DB_onserver2= '[database416541]',
       @table_that_changes = 'LossTable_2191'
```

What's the best way to store these values so I could do the equivilant of (for example)

```
select * from @linked_server1.@DB_onserver1.dbo.table1
```

that works throughout a script that contains lots of select statements?

Comment: look this :["Global variables" in SQL Server](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/04/23/60185.aspx)

Comment: u know in my idea the way you are expecting is not possible.you are gonna to behave with a variable like a database or something like that.I think it's better to store your information in a table as a global variables.

Comment: You'd have to do everything as dynamic SQL, which will make the scripts far less readable - T-SQL is a simple language, and where it expects a database name, it expects a *name*, not a *string* (nor, in turn, a variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but one approach would be to script views on the tables from the remote servers using dynamic sql along the lines of (not tested)

```
declare @table_that_changes varchar(100) 
declare @linked_server1 varchar(20)
declare @linked_server2 varchar(20)
declare @DB_onserver1 varchar(100) 
declare @DB_onserver2 varchar(100)
select @linked_server1 = '[server109]',
       @linked_server2 = '[server104]',
       @DB_onserver1 = '[database203434]',
       @DB_onserver2= '[database416541]',
       @table_that_changes = 'LossTable_2191'

declare @sql varchar(1000)

set @sql = 'create view linked1.table1 as select * from ' +
           @linked_server2 + '.' + @DB_onserver1  + '.table1'

exec( @sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you've already accepted another answer, [SQLCMD scripting variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx) are intended to handle exactly this sort of task.

Answer (score -1):

Unless there is a GO in your script the variables should remain in scope throughout the script.  My guess is you have 1 or more GO's which restarts the statements and clears any assigned variables.

Comment: This doesn't really answers the question. Op wants to do something that can't be done without dynamic SQL, nothing to do with `GO`s